# unit test dropdown component in react not covered

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, next.js

i have dropdown component using IBM carbon react

```
<Dropdown
          data-testid="groups"
          onChange={(groupid) => {
            const groupValue = groupid.selectedItem.value;
            setGroup(groupValue);
          }}
        />
```

i create test like this using testing library react, but onchange function not covered, please help me

```
const group = screen.getByTestId('groups');
  fireEvent.change(group, {
    target: {
      selectedItem: {
        id: 'id',
        parent_type: 'type',
        type: 'GROUP',
        value: 'group1',
        description: 'GROUP 1',
        label: 'GROUP 1',
      },
    },
  });
```